# Disabling ES Client Certificate Checks

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to disable the server from checking the clients?

Even when I have this set:

xpack.security.http.ssl.client_authentication: none

When I try to import anything using a script I get this:

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[?:?]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

I can browse to the ES server on 9200 fine from the client.

Comment: can you please provide more info, such as are you running in docker? on specific OS? what is the output of curl? which version of ES?